# Can you set value of Angular Material mat-button-toggle-group to an object?

Tags: angular, angular-material

All the examples I've seen are setting the `[value]` to a string or number - I have set it up to an object, but the emitted value is `[object Object]` not the actual object value I am working with.

Thoughts?

Comment: How did you verify the emitted value is `[object Object]`? Did you use a `console.log`?

Comment: debug in chrome console.

Comment: Can you please show some code? `[object Object]` means it is returning an object, as per your requirement. How does your object look and what value of the object do you require?

Comment: ok I have it working with the object - your comment helped me narrow down what I was doing wrong but the button has no `mat-button-toggle-checked` css class applied to it when I use objects.